# Reverse _contains() query in peewee

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

I have a sqlite3 db of Music which has a column named "Album".
Is there a way peewee can query all rows where the Album is a substring of a given string `str` - NOT the other way round?

From what I can see, we can query rows where `str` is a substring of `Album` but not the other way round:

```
#This works
q_str='anthem for the '
query=Music.select().where((Music.ALBUMARTIST == album_artist) & (Music.ALBUM.contains(qstr)) )
```

However in my case `q_str` would be something like `'anthem for the underdog (bonus track version)'`

So I would actually want to perform query like this:

```
#Query should return a row where Music.ALBUM is 'anthem for the underdog'

q_str='anthem for the underdog (bonus track version)'
query=Music.select().where((Music.ALBUMARTIST == album_artist) & (Music.ALBUM.is_in(qstr)) )
```

The _in() opertator only works with Lists which isn't suitable in my usecase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
from peewee import Value

q_str='anthem for the underdog (bonus track version)'
query = (Music
         .select()
         .where(
             (Music.ALBUMARTIST == album_artist) & 
             (Value(q_str).contains(Music.ALBUM))))
```